# Github actions CI can't upgrade V8 past 3.14

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, github-actions

I'm trying to set up CI for an R package using Github Actions. The package has a dependency on V8 >3.14, but I can't seem to get my workflow to upgrade past that version when its getting set up on Ubuntu (xenial or bionic). My workflow step for installing system dependencies is currently:

```
  - name: Install system dependencies
    if: runner.os == 'Linux'
    env:
      RHUB_PLATFORM: linux-x86_64-ubuntu-gcc
    run: |
      # install spatial dependencies and v8 modern
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cran/v8 --yes
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable --yes
      sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes update -qq
      sudo apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev libproj-dev libgeos++-dev libgdal-dev libnode-dev
      sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

I've tried various combinations of adding the required repositories and updating/upgrading. I can't see any error messages in the resultant logs, but V8 just won't upgrade. What am I missing? I don't have any trouble getting this to work on WSL-2 locally.

Comment: Have you tried adding libv8-dev to the list of installed dependencies?

Comment: Yes. That said, its apparently now an alias of libnode-dev and not expected to have an effect.